# epoll_wait - is there any reason for maxevents not to be 1?

Tags: epoll

When calling epoll_wait you pass in an event array for the returned events.

Is there any reason for this not to be a single element? eg:

```
epoll_event ev;
epoll_wait(fd, &ev, /*maxevents=*/1, /*timeout=*/-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code for epoll_wait and the only reason I can see for having more than 1 event is that it avoids multiple trips into the kernel which may be a performance hit.